# How to match aa sequence in list with DNA sequence in another list python

Tags: python

I have two list in python with different elements. Two list look like:

list1

```
[['Name:CRR58_ARATH'], ['Accession:Q9FHD4'], ['Fecha:2003-10-31'], ['Fullname:Cysteine-rich', 'repeat', 'secretory', 'protein', '58'], ['Secuencia:METTKKLFALLCLFVTMNQAISVSDPDDMETFCMKSSRNTTSNTTYNKNLNTLLSTLSNQSSFANYYNLTTGLASDTVHGMFLCTGDVNRTTCNACVKNATIEIAKNCTNHREAIIYNVDCMVRYSDKFFLTTLETNPSYWWSSNDLIPKSFGKFGQRLSDKMGEVIVRSSLLSSSFTPYYLMDTTRFDNLYDLESIVQCTPDLDPRNCTTCLKLALQELTECCGNQVWAFIYTPNCMVSFDTYNSSLPPLPPPSRSGSFSHRGNNKLLGGMVLAVSVSVFAFLSLV'], ['Name:011R_FRG3G'], ['Accession:Q6GZW4'], ['Fecha:2011-06-28'], ['Fullname:Uncharacterized', 'protein', '011R'], ['Secuencia:MTSVKTIAMLAMLVIVAALIYMGYRTFTSMQSKLNELESRVNAPQLRPPVMSPIVPLNFIESEDLDKELD'], ['Name:117L_IIV3'], ['Accession:Q196U3'], ['Fecha:2009-06-16'], ['Fullname:Uncharacterized', 'protein', '117L'], ['Secuencia:MEKQFNVWSVQNDIVCQRQLTINLRRVRNEYDNAVASVAAPSCPPSIPAQTRTCGRKLKLDWFKCTIL'], ['Name:12AH_CLOS4'], ['Accession:P21215'], ['Fecha:1991-08-01'], ['Fullname:12-alpha-hydroxysteroid', 'dehydrogenase'], ['Secuencia:MIFDGKVAIITGGGKAKSIGYGIAVAYAK'], ['Name:1106L_ASFB7'], ['Accession:P18556'], ['Fecha:2004-12-07'], ['Fullname:Protein', 'MGF', '110-6L'], ['Secuencia:MLVIFLGILGLLASQVSSQLVGQLRPTEDPPEEELEYWCAYMESCQFCWDCQDGTCINKIDGSAIYKNEYVKACLVSRWLDKCMYDLDKGIYHTMNCSQPWSWNPYKYFRKEWKKDEL']]
```

list2

```
[['161L', '20-Jun-94', 'HYDROLASE(O-GLYCOSYL)', 'MAFSAEDVLKEYDRRRRMEALLLSLYYPNDRKLLDYKEWSPPRVQVECPKAPVEWNNPPSEKGLIVGHFSGIKYKGEKAQASEVDVNKMCCWVSKFKDAMRRYQGIQTCKIPGKVLSDLDAKIKAYNLTVEGVEGFVRYSRVTKQHVAAFLKELRHSKQYENVNLIHYILTDKRVDIQHLEKDLVKDFKALVESAHRMRQGHMINVKYILYQLLKKHGHGPDGPDILTVKTGSKGVLYDDSFRKIYTDLGWKFTPL'], ['361D', '10-Nov-97', 'RNA', 'MSIIGATRLQNDKSDTYSAGPCYAGGCSAFTPRGTCGKDWDLGEQTCASGFCTSQPLCARIKKTQVCGLRYSSKGKDPLVSAEWDSRGAPYVRCTYDADLIDTQAQVDQFVSMFGESPSLAERYCMRGVKNTAGELVSRVSSDADPAGGWCRKWYSAHRGPDQDAALGSFCIKNPGAADCKCINRASDPVYQKVKTLHAYPDQCWYVPCAADVGELKMGTQRDTPTNCPTQVCQIVFNMLDDGSVTMDDVKNTINCDFSKYVPPPPPPKPTPPTPPTPPTPPTPPTPPTPPTPRPVHNRKVMFFVAGAVLVAILISTVRW'], ['261L', '11-May-99', 'HYDROLASE', 'MASNTVSAQGGSNRPVRDFSNIQDVAQFLLFDPIWNEQPGSIVPWKMNREQALAERYPELQTSEPSEDYSGPVESLELLPLEIKLDIMQYLSWEQISWCKHPWLWTRWYKDNVVRVSAITFEDFQREYAFPEKIQEIHFTDTRAEEIKAILETTPNVTRLVIRRIDDMNYNTHGDLGLDDLEFLTHLMVEDACGFTDFWAPSLTHLTIKNLDMHPRWFGPVMDGIKSMQSTLKYLYIFETYGVNKPFVQWCTDNIETFYCTNSYRYENVPRPIYVWVLFQEDEWHGYRVEDNKFHRRYMYSTILHKRDTDWVENNPLKTPAQVEMYKFLLRISQLNRDGTGYESDSDPENEHFDDESFSSGEEDSSDEDDPTWAPDSDDSDWETETEEEPSVAARILEKGKLTITNLMKSLGFKPKPKKIQSIDRYFCSLDSNYNSEDEDFEYDSDSEDDDSDSEDDC']
```

I'm trying to match list 1 protein sequence with protein sequence in list2 for example (list 1 sequence: MTVYDIDIS.... match in list2), transforming list1 and list2 in strings and I tried the following code:

```
strlist1 = str(list1.strip("[]"))
strlist2 = str(list2.strip("[]"))

if strlist1 in strlist2
   print("Sequence match", MTVYDIDIS......)
```

and it doesn't function.

Thank in advance.

Comment: Are you trying to find an exact match for any substring of elements following 'Secuencia:' in `list1` with any element at index 3 in `list2`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for full matches of (1) the substring to the right of 'Secuencia:' in nested list items in `list1` beginning with 'Secuencia:' with (2) the list element at index 3 in lists within `list2`, then the following code would work:

```
        list1 = [['Name:CRR58_ARATH'], ['Accession:Q9FHD4'], ['Fecha:2003-10-31'], ['Fullname:Cysteine-rich', 'repeat', 'secretory', 'protein', '58'], ['Secuencia:METTKKLFALLCLFVTMNQAISVSDPDDMETFCMKSSRNTTSNTTYNKNLNTLLSTLSNQSSFANYYNLTTGLASDTVHGMFLCTGDVNRTTCNACVKNATIEIAKNCTNHREAIIYNVDCMVRYSDKFFLTTLETNPSYWWSSNDLIPKSFGKFGQRLSDKMGEVIVRSSLLSSSFTPYYLMDTTRFDNLYDLESIVQCTPDLDPRNCTTCLKLALQELTECCGNQVWAFIYTPNCMVSFDTYNSSLPPLPPPSRSGSFSHRGNNKLLGGMVLAVSVSVFAFLSLV'], ['Name:011R_FRG3G'], ['Accession:Q6GZW4'], ['Fecha:2011-06-28'], ['Fullname:Uncharacterized', 'protein', '011R'], ['Secuencia:MTSVKTIAMLAMLVIVAALIYMGYRTFTSMQSKLNELESRVNAPQLRPPVMSPIVPLNFIESEDLDKELD'], ['Name:117L_IIV3'], ['Accession:Q196U3'], ['Fecha:2009-06-16'], ['Fullname:Uncharacterized', 'protein', '117L'], ['Secuencia:MEKQFNVWSVQNDIVCQRQLTINLRRVRNEYDNAVASVAAPSCPPSIPAQTRTCGRKLKLDWFKCTIL'], ['Name:12AH_CLOS4'], ['Accession:P21215'], ['Fecha:1991-08-01'], ['Fullname:12-alpha-hydroxysteroid', 'dehydrogenase'], ['Secuencia:MIFDGKVAIITGGGKAKSIGYGIAVAYAK'], ['Name:1106L_ASFB7'], ['Accession:P18556'], ['Fecha:2004-12-07'], ['Fullname:Protein', 'MGF', '110-6L'], ['Secuencia:MLVIFLGILGLLASQVSSQLVGQLRPTEDPPEEELEYWCAYMESCQFCWDCQDGTCINKIDGSAIYKNEYVKACLVSRWLDKCMYDLDKGIYHTMNCSQPWSWNPYKYFRKEWKKDEL']]
        
        list2 = [['161L', '20-Jun-94', 'HYDROLASE(O-GLYCOSYL)', 'MAFSAEDVLKEYDRRRRMEALLLSLYYPNDRKLLDYKEWSPPRVQVECPKAPVEWNNPPSEKGLIVGHFSGIKYKGEKAQASEVDVNKMCCWVSKFKDAMRRYQGIQTCKIPGKVLSDLDAKIKAYNLTVEGVEGFVRYSRVTKQHVAAFLKELRHSKQYENVNLIHYILTDKRVDIQHLEKDLVKDFKALVESAHRMRQGHMINVKYILYQLLKKHGHGPDGPDILTVKTGSKGVLYDDSFRKIYTDLGWKFTPL'], ['361D', '10-Nov-97', 'RNA', 'MSIIGATRLQNDKSDTYSAGPCYAGGCSAFTPRGTCGKDWDLGEQTCASGFCTSQPLCARIKKTQVCGLRYSSKGKDPLVSAEWDSRGAPYVRCTYDADLIDTQAQVDQFVSMFGESPSLAERYCMRGVKNTAGELVSRVSSDADPAGGWCRKWYSAHRGPDQDAALGSFCIKNPGAADCKCINRASDPVYQKVKTLHAYPDQCWYVPCAADVGELKMGTQRDTPTNCPTQVCQIVFNMLDDGSVTMDDVKNTINCDFSKYVPPPPPPKPTPPTPPTPPTPPTPPTPPTPPTPRPVHNRKVMFFVAGAVLVAILISTVRW'], ['261L', '11-May-99', 'HYDROLASE', 'MASNTVSAQGGSNRPVRDFSNIQDVAQFLLFDPIWNEQPGSIVPWKMNREQALAERYPELQTSEPSEDYSGPVESLELLPLEIKLDIMQYLSWEQISWCKHPWLWTRWYKDNVVRVSAITFEDFQREYAFPEKIQEIHFTDTRAEEIKAILETTPNVTRLVIRRIDDMNYNTHGDLGLDDLEFLTHLMVEDACGFTDFWAPSLTHLTIKNLDMHPRWFGPVMDGIKSMQSTLKYLYIFETYGVNKPFVQWCTDNIETFYCTNSYRYENVPRPIYVWVLFQEDEWHGYRVEDNKFHRRYMYSTILHKRDTDWVENNPLKTPAQVEMYKFLLRISQLNRDGTGYESDSDPENEHFDDESFSSGEEDSSDEDDPTWAPDSDDSDWETETEEEPSVAARILEKGKLTITNLMKSLGFKPKPKKIQSIDRYFCSLDSNYNSEDEDFEYDSDSEDDDSDSEDDC']]
        
        seqs1 = [x[0][len('Secuencia:'):] for x in list1 if x[0][:len('Secuencia:')] == 'Secuencia:']
        seqs2 = [x[3] for x in list2]
        print(seqs1)
        print()
        print(seqs2)
        
        set1 = set(seqs1)
        for seq in seqs2:
            if seq in set1:
                print(f"Sequence match {seq}")
```